# How to add UIDatePicker into textField in UIAlertController?

Tags: ios, swift, uidatepicker

I'm new in swift and I need help with my first app. I have UITableView with To Do tasks. I need help with adding a UIDatePicker in textField in UIAlertController.

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    self.setDatePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.dateChangeEvent), for: .valueChanged)
}

@IBAction func addNewTaskButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
    
    let toDoAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Add ToDo", message: "Add a new task", preferredStyle: .alert)
    toDoAlert.addTextField()
    
    toDoAlert.addTextField { textField in
       textField.inputView = self.setDatePicker
        
       let toolBar = UIToolbar()
       toolBar.barStyle = .default
       toolBar.isTranslucent = true
       toolBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
       toolBar.sizeToFit()
        
       let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(self.onClickDoneButton))
        toolBar.setItems([doneButton], animated: true)
        textField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
        
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium
        dateFormatter.timeStyle = .medium
        textField.text = dateFormatter.string(from: self.setDatePicker.date)
        
        self.view.endEditing(true)  
   }

@objc func onClickDoneButton() {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}

 @objc private func dateChangeEvent(_ dataPicker: UIDatePicker){
    toDoAlert.textFields?.first?.text = dataPicker.date.description
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add like this

```
let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
let toDoAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Add ToDo", message: "Add a new task", preferredStyle: .alert)
toDoAlert.addTextField { textField in
    textField.inputView = self.datePicker
}
```

Or

```
let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
let toDoAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Add ToDo", message: "Add a new task", preferredStyle: .alert)
toDoAlert.addTextField()
toDoAlert.textFields?.first?.inputView = datePicker
```

And for setting the picker value.

```
let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
let toDoAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Add ToDo", message: "Add a new task", preferredStyle: .alert)

@IBAction func showAlert(_ sender: UIButton) {
    datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(dateChangeEvent), for: .valueChanged)
    toDoAlert.addTextField { textField in
        textField.inputView = self.datePicker
    }
//=== Other Code ====
}

@objc private func dateChangeEvent(_ datePicker: UIDatePicker) {
    toDoAlert.textFields?.first?.text = datePicker.date.description
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I used the first solution. So I have one question if you can help me? Can I add a Done button toolbar and when it will be pressed, to set the date to textField?

Comment: By using the first solution. You will get textField in addTextField closure block. Now you can do anything the same as the normal text field. Just create a toolbar and set this toolbar to textField.

Comment: I edited my question(code). When I click on button to add task, the textField is filled with date. When I click on textFiled, it show me the picker view and the done button, but doesn't change the date. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Where you set date picker target ?

Comment: I don't know where to set that.

Comment: Add line to viewDidLoad

Comment: Can you see my code now? I edited but It does't write the date on textFiled when I pick and click on done button.

Comment: Just create to toDoAlert object outside the button action and add this code also in the done action. ```toDoAlert.textFields?.first?.text = dataPicker.date.description``` @BetYx

Comment: when I add outside the button action, then on every click on button, is adding a new two textFileds on sheet Action. (see secont photo in code)

Comment: @BetYx Just check this code. Create an alert controller object inside the action. https://stackoverflow.com/a/69433145/14733292

Comment: it's ok now, but my choesen date is appear on first textField. How to set to be on second? (see photo)